# android playstore app update strategies

Tags: android

Just need to know best practices while giving app update to Google play store in below scenarios.

1) App update due to significant changes in web services/api.
    a) existing user might not use the app as response from web services is changed.
    b) Can we have some good strategy which will allows us to minimize the breakdown time for existing users.
2) We are also thinking to enforce user to update the app.

Is there any good alternative. all we need to achieve minimal breakdown time for existing user and also new users can access the app seamlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> App update due to significant changes in web services/api. a) existing user might not use the app as response from web services is changed.

that's why every serious API is versioned. If you got backward incompatible changes, you just deploy new version of your API (i.e. 'https://api.foo.com/v2/....') and keep the old one for a while to let people who did not upgrade still use your app.

Comment: ok sounds good, will give it a try. Lets hope it will not hamper anything as we are changing the DB schema for diff versions of API.